# Pods errors on xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I am trying to update my xCode project with latest libraries, but I have errors building my project. Here are the details:

xcode 13.4.1
Cocoapods 1.11.3

Here is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'la soundbox' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'FirebaseCore'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore'
  pod 'FirebaseAuth'
  pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
  pod 'FirebaseInAppMessaging'
  pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
  pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics'
  pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end
end
```

Before installing anything, here is what I do:

- Clear Build folder
- Exit xCode
- Run those commands

  ```
   rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods 
   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/* 
   rm -rf /path_to_project/Pods 
   rm /path_to_project/Podfile.lock
  ```
- Restart mac
- Launch xCode and build project

I have this error that keeps coming up (From **FirebaseInAppMessaging** pod, in **FIRInAppMessaging.m**):

> 'FirebaseCore/FIRAppInternal.h' file not found

> Did not find header 'FIRAppInternal.h' in framework 'FirebaseCore'

What could be done to avoid this error ? I'm struggling on this and I really don't know what can I can do anymore